# Conditional Cell Contents on Grouping status

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to have the value of a cell change if a specific set of grouped cells are hidden or not. Is there a worksheet change action for grouping and ungrouping cells? I can't seem to generate one with Macro Recorder; it doesn't seem to care if cells are hidden or unhidden in a group. Then, I can have a macro change the value of the cell in question - I presume easier than coding the cell itself.

Context:

There are 5 lines, one being a total, and the other 4 the accounts making up the total. There is a merged vertical cell across all 5 rows with the title. I like to hide the 4 accounts, but when I do, the merged title cell only diplays enough to fit into one line, so I'd like it to then revert to an abbreviation (which I would provide).

It's a bit esoteric and pointless, but any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This post gives the essentials of what I needed:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=87457